# How to setup email notification alert in IIS 6.0 web server when a file is uploaded via any ftp client?

Tags: email, iis, vbscript, ftp

I'm trying to setup email notification alerts in IIS 6 when a file is uploaded via any FTP client. Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

I found something similar but don't understand how to implement it:
http://forums.iis.net/t/1196793.aspx/1?How+to+add+email+notification+service+in+IIS+6+0+when+a+file+is+uploaded+via+FTP+

Does anyone have any insight on this?

```
function countFolders(strPath)
   dim objShell
   dim objFolder
   dim folderCount

   set objShell = CreateObject("shell.application")
   set objFolder = objShell.NameSpace(strPath)

   if (not objFolder is nothing) then
      dim objFolderItems

      set objFolderItems = objFolder.Items

      if (not objFolderItems Is Nothing) then
         folderCount=objFolderItems.Count
      end if

      set objFolderItem = nothing
   end if

   set objFolder = nothing
   set objShell = nothing

   countFolders=folderCount
end function
```

Comment: How are the files being uploaded? Via your own software/website or via other third party programs like FileZilla?

Answer (score 0):

The post you're citing basically suggests this:

1. Create a script which checks the number of files in a folder(or folders) (as you have).
2. Create a running total of number of files. Maybe save this value into a database or another txt file.
3. If the number of files differs from the last time the check was ran, then send the email.

It suggests using scheduled tasks. This means an email is sent exactly when the FTP is updated only when you script is executed. The good thing about [Windows Tasks](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-GB/windows7/schedule-a-task) is you can run it as often as you like. So, assuming you don't need an immediate notification, you could set your script to run once a minute, once every 10 minutes or similar.

The problem with the above though is if people are removing files as well, you'll probably get missed notifications. EG assuming you don't want to be notified when a file is removed, this means if my current count of files is 10, 3 and removed and 1 added, this means next time the script runs I have 8 files. There is no way to know that files had been removed/re-added. In this case, you want to take a notice of the file-names and paths, make a note of them so you can compare existing paths to previous paths!

I have just completed a very similar task, but I had an extra luxury. I wrote the FTP client which had to be installed on all clients machines to send files to my FTP. This meant, in my FTP program, I had an extra bit of code which did: *OnUploadCompleted -> Send Notofication Email*

Answer (score 0):

You could create a service which uses the [FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x7t1d0ky.aspx).

The FileSystemWatcher listens to files system change notifications. In the provided link is a good example how to use the class.